# Creating Docker image from a running container with its volume

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to crate an image from one of my Jenkins container where I have create a pipeline. Now I want to share that whole Jenkins with those pipeline jobs as an image to my other teammates.

I tried  using docker commit

```
docker commit -m "Jenkins with AWS pipeline setup" -a "User" 2b01xdxx9d8f pipeline/jenkins:v1
```

then I did `docker save pipeline/jenkins:v1 > jenkins.tar`
and shared the .tar file with my team but when they loaded the .tar file  `docker load < jenkins.tar`
they got back to fresh Jenkins my pipeline my users where not there . is there any way to load the data too in the image .

Comment: Most likely you defined a volume when you started the container. You need to share this volume as well. I don't think you can do that as part of the save. Do it separately.

Comment: You should pretty much never use `docker commit`.  Describe the changes you want to make in a Dockerfile, commit it to source control, and `docker build` a new image.  If you need an unmodified Jenkins image plus data, you'll need to manage the data separately; the standard Jenkins images are configured so that the image never contains data (even after a commit).